# Algolia autocomplete - how to make responsive

Tags: jquery, css, typeahead.js, algolia, twitter-typeahead

I'm trying to implement Algolia's autocomplete (which I believe is built off Twitter's Typeahead?), following the example on their site: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/auto-complete/

Is it possible to make the dropdown responsive? Eg on that page, making the 'Rich horizontal UI' example horizontal on bigger screens but stack vertically on smaller screens (I'm using Bootstrap so thinking in terms of col-xs-12, col-sm-6 style)

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution - following the example on that page, just change the width CSS for .aa-dropdown-menu > div. Eg make it 100% for smaller screens and 50% for bigger screens